# I have an error after installing a few dependecies related to react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

`_reactNative.Dimensions.removeEventListener is not a function.`
this is the error thrown by the console, it does not say anything about navigation or anything related to my code that is why I think is a dependency issue, please help.

this are some of the dependencies I have

```
   "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.11.2",
```

[error displayed in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDG9y.png)

I tried installing other versions but I need those for the tutorial I am following, it might not be updated though

Comment: here is the github repo https://github.com/Ceci007/react-native-styled-components

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, guys. I figured it out, I am now using `react-navigation` version 6 and the code goes like this:

```
    import React from "react";
    import { createStore } from "redux";
    import { Provider } from "react-redux";
    import HomeScreen from "./screens/HomeScreen";
    import SectionScreen from "./screens/SectionScreen";
    import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
    import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
    import Ionicons from "@expo/vector-icons/Ionicons";
    
    const initialState = {
      action: "",
      name: "",
    };
    
    const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case "OPEN_MENU":
          return { action: "openMenu" };
        case "CLOSE_MENU":
          return { action: "closeMenu" };
        case "UPDATE_NAME":
          return { name: action.name };
        default:
          return state;
      }
    };
    
    const store = createStore(reducer);
    
    const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
    
    const App = () => (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Tab.Navigator
            screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
              tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
                let iconName;
                if (route.name === "Home") {
                  iconName = focused ? "ios-home" : "ios-home-outline";
                } else if (route.name === "Courses") {
                  iconName = focused ? "ios-albums" : "ios-albums-outline";
                } else if (route.name === "Projects") {
                  iconName = focused ? "ios-folder" : "ios-folder-outline";
                }
                return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={26} color={color} />;
              },
              tabBarActiveTintColor: "#4775f2",
              tabBarInactiveTintColor: "#b8bece",
              headerShown: false,
            })}
          >
            <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
            <Tab.Screen name="Courses" component={SectionScreen} />
            <Tab.Screen name="Projects" component={SectionScreen} />
          </Tab.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      </Provider>
    );
    
    export default App;
```